# How can I substring an ID?

Tags: c#, split, substring

I got a `ID` 
which are  **LSHOE-UCT**. How can I substring and seperate those `ID` in order to become:

```
gender = "L"
Product = "Shoe"
Category = "UCT"
```

Here is my code:

```
    private void assignProductCategory(string AcStockCategoryID)
    {
        //What should I insert?
        string[] splitParameter = AcStockCategoryID.Split('-');

    }
```

I need to seperate those, ID them and insert to difference table from my database. And that is where I am having the main problem

Comment: What does "L" stand for? Is it restricted to have a value from some fixed possible values?

Comment: @walther: If it's about shoes and other related products, maybe "ladies"?  As in the Ladies' Department vs. the Men's Department.  Just a guess.

Comment: @David, yes, probably you're right. I just wanted to be sure before suggesting any real solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string[] s = AcStockCategoryID.Split('-');
string gender = s[0].Substring(0, 1);
string Product= s[0].Substring(1, s[0].Length - 1);
string Category = s[1];
```

Answer (score 1):

try this, I just typed it randomly apologies if there are any typos...

```
string id = "LSHOE-UCT";    
string[] arr = id.Split('-');
string gender = id.Substring(0,1); // this will give you L
string product = arr[0].Substring(1); // this will give you shoe
string category = arr[1]; // this will give you UCT;
```

Answer (score 1):

***EDIT: Updated my answer due to the ID format not being correct in my first post.***

If your `acStockCategoryID` is always going to be in the format of `LSHOE-UTC`, then you could do something like the following:

```
private void assignProductCategory(string AcStockCategoryID) 
{
    string[] splitParameter = AcStockCategoryID.Split('-');
    System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();

    sb.AppendLine("gender=" + splitParameter[0].Substring(0, 1));
    sb.AppendLine("Product=" + splitParameter[0].Substring(1));
    sb.AppendLine("Category=" + splitParameter[1]);

    // use sb.ToString() wherever you need the results
}
```

Comment: @Fuex - I figured that out, that's why I had the `EDIT: This answer is assuming all of your IDs are separated by -.` in my post. I had edited it again prior to your downvote to include the other code as well.

Comment: I'm sorry, revalued answer :).

Comment: Hi , thanks for ur comment. btw hw can i substring to get LSHOE?

Comment: @user998405 - You wouldn't need to substring to get LSHOE. The `Split('-')` gets you `"LSHOE"` with `splitParameter[0]` and `"UTC"` with `splitParameter[1]`.

Answer (score 1):

To try a different approach, this would work, too.

```
string id = "LSHOE-UCT";
string gender = id.Substring(0,1);

int indexOfDash = id.IndexOf("-");
string product = id.Substring(1, indexOfDash - 1);

string category = id.Substring(indexOfDash + 1);
```

Comment: Hi , thanks for ur comment. btw hw can i substring to get LSHOE?

Answer (score 1):

**Warning**: Complete Overkill

You could also use LINQ's extension methods (`IEnumerable`) to accomplish this.  I thought I'd have a little thought experiment about how you could use `IEnumerable` to over-engineer a solution:

```
int indexOfDash = id.IndexOf("-");

var firstPart = id.TakeWhile(s => s != '-');
var linqGender = firstPart.Take(1).ToArray()[0];  // string is L
var linqProduct = String.Join("", firstPart.Skip(1).Take(indexOfDash-1)); // string is SHOE

var secondPart = id.Skip(indexOfDash+1);
var linqCategory = String.Join("", secondPart);  //string is UCT
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do it backwards.

```
public class LCU
{
    public string Gender {get; set;}
    public string Product {get; set;} 
    public string Category {get; set;}
    public LCU(){}
}

private static LSU LShoe_UctHandler(string id)
{
    var lcu = new LCU();
    var s = id.Split('-');
    if (s.length < 2) throw new ArgumentException("id");
    lcu.Category = s[1];
    lcu.Gender = s[0].Substring(0,1);
    lcu.Product = s[0].Substring(1);
    return lcu;
}
```

Then just pass ID to LShoe_UctHandler like so...

```
var lcu = LShoe_UctHandler("LGlobtrotters-TrainingShoes");
Console.WriteLine("gender = {0}", lcu.Gender);       
Console.WriteLine("Product = {0}", lcu.Product );         
Console.WriteLine("Category = {0}", lcu.Category );
```

[Hand keyed - so sorry for typos and casing errors]

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
        string id = "LSHOE-UCT";
        Console.WriteLine("Gender: {0}",id.Substring(0,1));
        Console.WriteLine("Product: {0}",id.Split('-')[0].Substring(1));
        Console.WriteLine("Product: {0}", id.Split('-')[1]);
```